# Alterando el atributo title HTML con jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito alterar los atributos HTML title usando jQuery.
Por ejemplo, si existe un atributo title llamado "A" entonces cámbielo por un atributo title llamado "B"

```
if($(document).attr("title", "A"))
{
    $(document).attr("title", "B");
}
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer eso?

Comment: Con la línea `$(document).attr("title", "B");` estás cambiando de forma correcta el `title` de la página, pero ¿para qué pones `if($(document).attr("title", "A"))`? Siempre se va a ejecutar lo que está dentro de ese `if`. Si lo que quieres es chequear si el `title` de la página es `A` y luego cambiarlo a `B`, entonces deberías de ponerlo así: `if($(document).attr('title')=='A')`

Comment: Corregí a la forma como tu me lo has indicado y no funciona, infelizmente.

Comment: @JuanRivera lo que necesito es cambiar un title attribute html conocido por otro. Si existe un attribute title HTML llamado "A" cambielo por un attribute title llamado "B". Todo eso con jQuery.

Comment: `$(document).attr("title", "B");` te cambia el atributo `title` de la página, no el atributo `title` de cualquier elemento que tenga dicho atributo.

Comment: @MiSCapu, si lo que quieres es cambiar el `title` de 'A' a 'B' de cualquier elemento que contenga el atributo `title` igual a 'A', entonces puedes utilizar este selector sin nada más: `$('[title="A"]').attr('title','B');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

creo deberia ser asi:

```
if($(document).attr("title") == "A")
{
    $(document).attr("title", "B");
}
```

porque el segundo argumento es para setear, para obtener se usa solo con 1 argumento

```
<div data-atributo="A">SI FUNCIONA</div>
```

```
if($("div").attr("data-atributo") == "A")
{ 
  $("div").attr("data-atributo", "B");
}
console.log($("div").attr("data-atributo"))
```

Comment: Eso no funciona

Comment: compruebalo tu mismo

Comment: Acabé de comprobarlo Hernán; sin duda funciona perfectamente; muchas gracias!